# moving a shape across a jframe

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Basically my entire program is to have shapes move across a JFrame,
and the problem I am having is that I cannot get my object to move.

I have a class called Creatures and the constructor creates my body and tail of my fish.
(I'm making an aquarium). This class extends to another class that has a move() method, so that everytime a timer event happens the picture moves.

Again my problem is that I cannot get the picture/shape/object to move.
If anyone could lend a hand I would be most grateful =]

Here is the full class of Creatures

```
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Creatures extends Moveable2DShape{

    private Color color;
    private int delay, number;
    private int xPos2, yPos2;
    private final int POINTS = 3;
    private int []x = new int[POINTS];
    private int []y = new int[POINTS];
    private double width, height;
    Ellipse2D.Double body;
    Polygon tail;

    public Creatures(int xPos, int yPos, int shapeWidth, int shapeHeight, int bwidth, int bheight, double xSpeed, double ySpeed, Color c){
        super(xPos, yPos, shapeWidth, shapeHeight, bwidth, bheight, xSpeed, ySpeed);
        color = c;
        xPos2 = xPos;
        yPos2 = yPos;
        width = shapeWidth;
        height = shapeHeight;


    }

    public Polygon triangle(int xPos, int yPos){


        x[0] = xPos + 100;
        x[1] = x[0];
        x[2] = (int)(xPos + width/2);

        y[0] = (int)(yPos + (height));
        y[1] = yPos;
        y[2] = (int)(yPos + height/2);
        tail = new Polygon(x,y,POINTS);

        return tail;

    }

       //public void move(){
         }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g){
        body = new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos2, yPos2, width, height);
        //System.out.println(xPos2 + " " + yPos2 + " " + width + " " + height);
        triangle(xPos2, yPos2);

        g.setColor(color);
        g.fill(body);
        g.fill(tail);


    }


}
```

I'm supposed to override the move() method that is inherited from the Moveabled2DShape class but i havent yet because I just wanted to test out the method before overriding it.  But now my problem is that I need to update xPos2 and yPos2

Comment: I think that we need a bit more information to be able to help you in any meaningful way. You don't show any code that suggests it's the source of the problem for one.  Have you added debug statements to your code?  For more suggestions on what we need, please check out: [How to Ask Smart Questions](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: Does Creatures derive from some JComponent?

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy
I have a class that extends to the JComponent class that calls a method to addFish into an arraylist, which there it would create a Creature object

Comment: @lalalalla if you've solved it then please share the solution.

Comment: @Boro sorry for the late reply i've been busy with school..i posted up the solution =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MY FULL SOLUTION OF THE CREATURES CLASS

```
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Creatures extends Moveable2DShape{

    private Color color;
    private int delay, number, t;
    private int xPos, yPos;
    private double xSpeed, ySpeed;
    private final int POINTS = 3;
    private int []x = new int[POINTS];
    private int []y = new int[POINTS];
    private double width, height;
    private boolean dead;
    Ellipse2D.Double body;
    Polygon tail;

    public Creatures(int xPos, int yPos, int shapeWidth, int shapeHeight, int bwidth, int bheight, double xSpeed, double ySpeed, Color c, int type, boolean l){
        super(xPos, yPos, shapeWidth, shapeHeight, bwidth, bheight, xSpeed, ySpeed);
        color = c;
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
        this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
        width = shapeWidth;
        height = shapeHeight;
        t = type;
        dead = l;

    }

    /*@x[3] calculate the x position points of the tail
     *@y[3] calculate the y position points of the tail
     *@tail create the polygon using the points and a defined constant of 3
     *@return the polygon @tail*/
    public Polygon triangle(int xP, int yP){
        x[0] = xP + 100;
        x[1] = x[0];
        x[2] = (int)(xP + width/2);

        y[0] = (int)(yP + (height));
        y[1] = yP;
        y[2] = (int)(yP + height/2);

        tail = new Polygon(x,y,POINTS);

        return tail;

    }

    /*@newBW will determine the new width of the bounding box
     *@return the new bounding box width*/
    public int newBWidth(){
        int newBW;

        newBW = (int)(x[0] - getBoundingBoxMaxX()) + (int)getBoundingBoxWidth();
        return newBW;
    }

    /*when called, the move method of Creatures will move along the x-values\
     *set the new bounding box with the new calculated width */
    public void move(){

        this.xPos=(int) (getXPos() - xSpeed);

        int overShoot = (int) (xPos + getBoundingBoxWidth() - environmentWidth);
        if (xPos <= 0)
        {
          xPos = 0;
          xSpeed = -xSpeed ;
        }
        else if (overShoot > 0)
        {
          xPos = (int)(environmentWidth - getBoundingBoxWidth());
          xSpeed = - xSpeed ;
        }
        /*
          Reflect the object if it goes too far
        */
        overShoot = (int) (yPos + getBoundingBoxHeight() - environmentHeight);
        if (yPos <= 0)
        {
          yPos = 0;
          ySpeed = -ySpeed ;
        }
        else if (overShoot > 0)
        {
          yPos = (int) (environmentHeight - getBoundingBoxHeight());
          ySpeed = - ySpeed ;
        }

        if(xPos == 0 || xPos == 880){
            this.yPos =+ (int)(getYPos() + ySpeed);
        }
        if(yPos == 650){
            this.yPos =+ (int)(getYPos() + ySpeed);
        }

        // move the shape to the new position
        moveTo(xPos,yPos);
        setBoundingBox(getXPos() , getYPos() , newBWidth(), height);
    }

    /*Detect if two bounding boxes intersects with one another if two intersects
     *call the collision response method and @return true, else @return false. */
    public boolean collisionDetect(Moveable2DShape other){
        if(getBoundingBox().intersects(other.getBoundingBox())){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*@other2 cast the Moveable2DShape object into a Creatures object and compare
     *if @other2 object type is greater than the current object then the current object dies
     *if the two objects are equal to each other then change the color of both objects randomly
     *otherwise @other2 dies. */
    public void collisionResponse(Moveable2DShape other){
        int []c2 = new int[3];
        int []c3 = new int[3];

        Creatures other2 = (Creatures) other;
        if (getType() < other2.getType()){
            fishiesDie();
        }else if(getType() == other2.getType()){
            for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++){
                c2[a] = (int)(Math.random()*255) + 1;
                c3[a] = (int)(Math.random()*255) + 1;
            }
            color = new Color(c2[0], c2[1], c2[2]);
            other2.color = new Color(c3[0], c3[1], c3[2]);
        }else{
            other2.fishiesDie();
        }

    }


    /*@return the type of the fish */
    public int getType(){
        return t;
    }

    /*@dead equals to true when called */
    public void fishiesDie(){
        dead = true;
    }

    /*@return dead */
    public boolean isDead(){
        return dead;
    }

    /*@body draw the general body ellipse
     *@g set the colour and draw the general fish shape(body and tail)*/
    public void draw(Graphics2D g){
        body = new Ellipse2D.Double((int)getXPos(), (int)getYPos() , width, height);
        triangle((int)getXPos(), (int)getYPos());
        //g.draw(getBoundingBox());
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fill(body);
        g.fill(tail);


    }


}
```